# How to insert b'\x1bB\x85' in MySQL's BLOB column from Python?

Tags: python, mysql, blob, pymysql

I am trying to insert the `bytes` in `BLOB` Type column in Python using `pymysql`.

The requirement is the byte should not be encoded when inserting.

My SQL looks like as follows when executing:

`insert into product values(b'<\xf0Q,\x18\x99y\x86\xda\x81\xc8\x869Q\xf8\xc9\xb2\xc6NqG\xcfV\xbf{\x86\xf8\nJ\x0b\xfa)');`

Getting the following error while trying to insert.

```
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "home/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "home/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "home/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "home/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "home/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "home/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "home/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "home/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'<\\xf0Q,\\x18\\x99y\\x86\\xda\\x81\\xc8\\x869Q\\xf8\\xc9\\xb2\\xc6NqG\\xcfV\\xbf{\\x86\\xf8\\nJ' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use parameter substitution pymysql will handle the bytes correctly.

```
>>> import pymysql
>>> conn = pymysql.connect(database='test')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE t70182867 (id int not null auto_increment, data blob, primary key(id))""")
0
>>> bs = b'<\xf0Q,\x18\x99y\x86\xda\x81\xc8\x869Q\xf8\xc9\xb2\xc6NqG\xcfV\xbf{\x86\xf8\nJ\x0b\xfa)'
>>> sql = """INSERT INTO t70182867 (data) VALUES (%s)"""
>>> cur.execute(sql, (bs,))  # <= let pymysql handle the values
1
>>> conn.commit()
>>> cur.execute("""SELECT data FROM t70182867""")
1
>>> cur.fetchone()
(b'<\xf0Q,\x18\x99y\x86\xda\x81\xc8\x869Q\xf8\xc9\xb2\xc6NqG\xcfV\xbf{\x86\xf8\nJ\x0b\xfa)',)
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved the error.